# install and activated mcrypt for php in specific directory

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have two différent version of php installed on my server and i want to

activate mcrypt for both :

1. `/etc/php`: mcrypt installed and activated (via yum ) => done
2. `/appli/php`: I can't install mcrypt (*I edited `php.ini` to add `mcrypt.so` but it doesn't work*)

Could you help me how can i **install and activated mcrypt** for php located in

`/appli/php` (specific folder)?

Available for more informations needed.

Comment: And "but it doesn't work" means what _exactly_? What happens if you restart the process? Anything in the error log?

Comment: unable to load module,
I have installed mcrypt by yum and put extension="path of mcrypt.so"

Comment: Could you please post the _full_ error message? So _why_ the extension cannot be loaded?

Comment: [27-Feb-2018 13:25:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Ah, ok, there you have your answer: you try to load an incompatible module. Reads like you grabbed some package from some source which does not really match the one you got your php packages from.

Comment: My problem is how to install the module in a specific directory /appli/php and then load it

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand that last question. You need to modify that ``php.ini`` file that is read by the php process you want to load the module into (check `phpinfo()` for that). In there you insert the `LoadModule` command using the absolute path to the module file (library file).

Comment: The problem is how to install the package of mcrypt and make it working with the second php installed in my server.
I have installed mcrypt with yum and configure it in two different version of php ( both are 5.**) the php in /etc/php works and /appli/php doesnt work

Comment: Sure, I understood that far. However you can also see the error message you get: the module is not accepted by one of the php versions since it does not match it's API version. You need two separate mcrypt modules, once for each php version. Not different versions of the mcrypt module, but compiler against different php versions. Then, when you have installed those separate modules, then you can instruct each php version to load that module that matches the API version.

Comment: How to install two separate mcrypt, thats the question

Comment: Well, you installed two different versions of php. So either you have two separate repositories or you created packages yourself. Why can't you do the same with that module?

Comment: I come i find two php in different repository ( it is not me who made the install) i want to add mcrypt module thats all :)

Comment: Sure, so install the matching module from the respective repository. If it is not offered, then you will have to build it yourself. Check the build options used in the other php packages you installed from those repositories.

Comment: I just wonder why that is such a problem... Could it be that you do not know how to use software repositories in a Linux software management system? If so you really want to find out!